# IPTables: allow outgoing SSH

Tags: ssh, iptables

I tried to write my rules for securing a web server with just http/https, apt-get updates, sending mails SSH access.
So far I've done that:

```
IPT=/sbin/iptables
$IPT -F
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -F
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t mangle -F
$IPT -t mangle -X
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
#
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --STATE ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -m state --STATE ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#
# Allow All for SSH
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
#
# Allow all for HTTP / HTTPS
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#
# Allow loopback traffic
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
#    
# Allow to be pinged ( Outside => srv )
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
#
# Allow outgoing DNS connections
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
#
# Apt-get
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 32786:61000 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 32786:61000 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 32786:61000 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 32786:61000 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
#
# SMTP Outgoing
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 -d 0/0 --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 25 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED-j ACCEPT
#
# Prevent DoS
#$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 60/minute --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 100 --connlimit-mask 32     -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
#
# Log dropped packets
$IPT -N LOGGING
$IPT -A INPUT -j LOGGING
$IPT -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: "     --log-level 7
$IPT -A LOGGING -j DROP
#
$IPT -L
```

But it seems I missed something for outgoing SSH to work (*from* this server *to* a remote, the other way works), but I can't find what. I also tried to ssh the destination by typing the IP in case some DNS stuff was blocked but that didn't work either.

I am pretty sure that those rules are the reason it doesn't work because it work well if I try to flush and accept all.

Here is the iptables -L -n output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
 target     prot opt source               destination
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED
 ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8
 ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spts:32786:61000 dpt:80
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 dpts:32786:61000
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:25 dpts:1024:65535 state ESTABLISHED
 REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 #conn/32 > 100 reject-with tcp-reset
 LOGGING    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

 Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
 target     prot opt source               destination

 Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
 target     prot opt source               destination
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
 ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 0
 ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spts:32786:61000 dpt:80
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 dpts:32786:61000
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:25 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

 Chain LOGGING (1 references)
 target     prot opt source               destination
 LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix `IPTables Packet Dropped: '
 DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to cover states in each rule instead of having one rule on top of the chain for established and related connections? That is considered standard practice.

Comment: @BelminFernandez He read a bad tutorial on the Internet. There are many of them, unfortunately.

Comment: No reason. Indeed, I just read some (obviously bad) stuff on the internet. I just didn't know I could do otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

When you have an outgoing connection, the destination port will be 22 so this should be the rule:

```
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Also, you should have one rule to cover `ESTABLISHED` and `RELATED` on top of the `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains:

```
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to edit the rules with your remarks (as well as in my question, above). Again, unfortunatly, it wasn't enough.

Comment: Can you refresh `iptables -L -n` and post in question?

Comment: Doesn't look like the new rules took effect. Clear your rules (be careful in not locking yourself out if you're doing this via ssh) and rerun the script you're using for the rules.

Comment: Yes they are, I redone it and checked. For instance, there is no longer the "state NEW,ESTABLISHED" after the spt/dpt:22 lines. What did you except to see for ssh to work ? (and thanks for the warning! I regularly lock myself.. good thing I also have a plugin-based keyboard/screen remote access stuff :))

Comment: The first rule under `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains should be the `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` rules but I do not see it there. I could very well be missing something (haven't had breakfast yet!).

Answer (score 5):

Your rule for outgoing SSH traffic doesn't include the `NEW` statement, required to initiate outgoing connections.

Comment: Thank you ! I understood and added it. 
Unfortunatly, that still doesn't work (still 'connection timed out', while it works if I flush & accept all)

I guess I also missed another thing.  

I didn't wrote it because I believe it doesn't matter but the connection is between 2 different ports ( port 22 on the server, then there is a router which route 22 to 24 on target ). Doesn't matter right ?

Comment: You're are writing that the target host is having an SSH serving listening on port 24 behind a router forwarding from 22 to 24. Could it that router the blocking point like misconfigured ? Based on the redirection, you are right to connect to port 22 as you should only care for public port of the target.

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic error when you doesn't understand client-server architecture and "stateful firewalls"

In a client-server architecture, the only port that is known a priori is the destination port because the client choose a ephemeral ports[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) , except some extremely rare exceptions like DHCP for example.

From the firewall point off view, every single packet expelled from it has state NEW especially in TCP connections.[2](http://www.iptables.info/en/connection-state.html)

First let's see what we have

```
IPT=/sbin/iptables
$IPT -F
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -F
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t mangle -F
$IPT -t mangle -X
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP

# Excellent!! because always we need to accept this kind of states because
# always are response packets, remember we can be client or server
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --STATE ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -m state --STATE ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow All for SSH
# this accept ssh connections from outside, and the response for this input
# is a outgoing packet with the state ESTABLISHED. (four lines above)
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# this rule are meaningless because you never start a ssh connection from
# source port 22, this because the source ports are choose randomly
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT

# this one let start a ssh connection from within to the outside and the response
# enter in state ESTABLISHED, 13 lines above
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow all for HTTP / HTTPS
# http servers are very basic if we think on client-server, they only respond a
# client request, except if some web software try to establish a network connection
# to the outside, for this block the only rule with meaning is the first, the rest are
# meaningless
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback traffic
# this are obligatory rules avoiding the firewall block himself
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow to be pinged ( Outside => srv )
# always the interpretation depends from the point of view
# with this rules you can accept ping request from outside and despond the request
# but you cannot ping from inside to outside because in that scenario you send the request (OUTPUT)
# and receive a reply from outside (INPUT) 
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT


# Allow outgoing DNS connections
# this allow send dns queries to the DNS server that you have registered in the file
# /etc/resolv.conf
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
# this one are meaningless because the response from the DNS server is ESTABLISHED and is 
# accepted in the very beginning in the firewall 
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Apt-get
# AFAIK apt use http or ftp, they can use https but is less common
# the specification of a range on source port are meaningless
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 32786:61000 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 32786:61000 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 32786:61000 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 32786:61000 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT

# SMTP Outgoing
# I don't known why you start adding more criteria without meaning 
# maybe you start surfing on the net and starting copy&paste code without see what you are doing
# always when yo need to learn something go to the root, or in this case to www.netfilter.org
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 -d 0/0 --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 25 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED-j ACCEPT


# the rules below are.... copy&paste from somewhere

# Prevent DoS
#$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 60/minute --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 100 --connlimit-mask 32     -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
#
# Log dropped packets
$IPT -N LOGGING
$IPT -A INPUT -j LOGGING
$IPT -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: "     --log-level 7
$IPT -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

So, to me, you need this firewall

```
IPT=/sbin/iptables
$IPT -F
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -F
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t mangle -F
$IPT -t mangle -X
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP

# accept a priori all the responses
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --STATE ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -m state --STATE ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow All for SSH 
# allow ssh connections from outside to inside
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# allow ssh connections from inside to outside
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow all for HTTP / HTTPS
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback traffic
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow to be pinged ( Outside => srv )
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
# from srv to outside
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing DNS connections
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Apt-get
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT

# SMTP Outgoing
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

I hope it has been helpful.
And sorry for my english, is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest rules (ignorgin state for now):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

This should do the trick. once it you try it and succeed, you can modify it to include state, source/destination IP addresses, different ports..